# How To Update the React js project from 15.6 to 16.8?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How To Update the React js project from 15.6 to 16.8? is there any Steps need to to be followed ?

Comment: You can read about the Updating React project to the latest version on the documentation page. [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to install the latest version that you want to upgrade to by running
`npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0`
or this if you are using yarn:
`yarn add react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0`
then run
`npm update --save` or in the case of yarn
`yarn update --save`
to get all packages that are dependent and the latest updates for all your packages.

Comment: If you want to get the next major version automatically just do this:
```npm add react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0``` then run the next command ```npm update --save```

Comment: its `yarn upgrade --save`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm update --save react` to update to latest version of react in your current project.

Or use `npm update --save react@[version]` for specific version.

Ex :- `npm update --save react@16.11`. In your case `npm update --save react@16.18`

And if you want to use globly then use `-g`.

Ex:- `npm update --save -g react@16.11`

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 way, directly and indirectly

1.directly: bin this code in the import of your code

*import update from 'react-update'*

2.indirectly: in terminal use, this command for update the react to the last version , also if you install it again, it will install the last version of react.js (npm install --g create-react-app)

`npm i --save react-update`

Answer (score 0):

you can use only two commands -

1 - npm install --save react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0

2 - npm update --save

after that you can check your react version using the following commands -

npm view react version